# How to run a function in caller context?

Tags: node.js

I have a function in a module that simulates shell.

```
function shell() { 
while(1) {
  let code = readline.question(">> ");
  if(code == "") continue;
  if(code == "exit") break;
  try {
      console.log(eval(code)); 
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
  }
}
}
module.exports = shell;
```

I'm calling this `shell` function inside another js file in hope of ***accessing all the variables and functions defined inside that caller function***. Like below:

```
const shell = require('./shell.js');    

var EXPIRY_DATES = ["28MAY2020"];
shell();

function parse_data() {
     return "somedata";
}
```

But I'm not able to access `EXPIRY_DATES` and `parse_data()` from inside the `shell`. How to do this?
(I tried `call` and `bind` but not successful.)

Comment: It's not possible to run a function and let it use the current scp[e. 1. It would be very dangerous for that to happen 2. functions will be pretty useless if they can be defined in one place but only work in a single other place. You can either place every in an object and pass it as `this` via `call`/`apply`/`bind` or you can pass these as parameter value(s).

Comment: *technically*, you can also use `eval` but I heavily advise against it.

Comment: Ohk thank you so much :) I'm new to programming and javascript... do you mean something like  `shell({EXPIRY_DATES: EXPIRY_DATES, parse_date: parse_date})` ?

Comment: there are so many functions and variables in the caller function :(

Comment: Yes, that will work. The function will then will then be able to use these from the parameter.

Comment: Is there an easier workaround? this is for personal use so no security issues... Thanks again @VLAZ for the fast response:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider passing an object containing the properties (variables) you want the other script to be able to access, then reference that object when `eval`ing:

```
function shell(vars) {
    const result = eval('vars.EXPIRY_DATES');
    console.log(result);
    // other code in shell
}
(() => {
    var EXPIRY_DATES = ["28MAY2020"];
    shell({ EXPIRY_DATES });
    module.exports = shell;
})();
```

Logged result:

```
[ '28MAY2020' ]
```